# Styling forms generated with different plugins

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, contact-form-7

**Premise:** I'm doing an Internship right now, so I am not a pro.

Hey Developers, I need your help.
I inherited a work from another guy in which I have to re-style 3 contact forms.

**Problem is:** two forms are generated in Wordpress with Contact form 7, and the last one is done using Woocommerce.
What's the best way to proceed to make all three forms consistent?
Do I override the styles of the theme with my own styles?
Any better solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is to identify the common fields.

In most cases you can add styling to the input and input[type="X"] fields.

This will mean not only will these forms be consistent but everything else that a form will be consistent.

E.g.

```
input {
    background: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 5px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: #333;
    color: white;
}
```

This will style all the inputs and then also target the input with the type submit.

In most cases these stylings will be ignored due to weight of the styling so it may be necessary to nest these inside classes and divs. Or just use !important to overide them.

E.g

```
//Overiding with !important
input {
    background: #f1f1f1 !important;
    padding: 5px !important;
}

//Nesting to give extra value
html body .container form input[type="submit"] {
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: #333;
    color: white;
}
```

More information on weights given to classes/id's/elements [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

More information on input types [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_form.asp).